# Taxonomy in URL

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, taxonomy, urls

I have a huge problem: I want to have nice URL's on my Homepage. I got a custom post type and taxonomies. Now I want to have a URL like that:

> www. mydomain .com/videos(Category)/funny(Taxonomy)/the-video(Post)

or

> www. mydomain .com/videos(Category)/sport(Taxonomy)/the-video(Post)

How do I get this? I am searching for about a year now...

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps below will make your permalinks look like: `www.mydomain.com/videos(Category)/the-video(Post)`

> 1. Visit the *Settings > Permalinks* page of your WordPress administration dashboard.
> 2. Select the **Custom Structure** option, and enter this value:
>
>    `/%category%/%postname%/`
> 3. Click **Save Changes**

There currently is no way (that I know of) to include the taxonomy in the permalink. One way around this is to instead assign *subcategories*, which will be incuded in the permalink.

eg: `www.mydomain.com/videos(Category)/funny(Subcategory)/the-video(Post)`

You can convert your existing taxonomies into top-level categories by visiting the *Tools > Import* page, and using the Categories and Tags Converter.

You can then convert the top-level categories into subcategories on the *Posts > Categories* page.